# Rackup: cannot load such file 'sinatra'

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I already installed sinatra gem and in `irb`, if I type,

```
require 'sinatra'
```

It returns `true`.

But when I do

```
rackup -d config.ru
```

It tells me

```
nil
Exception `LoadError' at /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - cannot load such file -- sinatra
```

---

Here is my `config.ru`

```
require './app'

set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
set :app_file,     'app.rb'
disable :run

run Sinatra::Application
```

`app.rb`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '' do
   'Hello World'
end
```

I don't know what is going wrong.

---

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ which rackup
/usr/local/bin/rackup
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-linux]
$ rackup -v
Rack 1.2 (Release: 1.5)
```

Comment: Can you do `require 'rack'` in irb?

Comment: @matt it returns `true`

Comment: Can you run the app directly with `ruby app.rb`?

Comment: @matt It gives `config.ru:3:in `<main>': undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. I suppose it needs rack environment.

Comment: It looks like you tried `ruby config.ru`. Try `ruby app.rb`. But given that it fails after requiring your app I think we’re closer to working out what’s happening. Can you give the results of `which ruby` and `which rackup`?

Comment: @matt I added the info in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that your rackup script is a binstub of a 'rack' gem
installed in a diff ruby1.9x vm

maybe earlier version of ruby1.9.2
so it can't see the sinatra installed

I'd try 'which rackup' on the command line

Comment: What the heck was the solution then!!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just the verbose output from setting the `-d` option. Does the server actually start (after producing a load of output)?

What’s happening is this. [Using `-d` sets Ruby’s `$DEBUG` flag to `true`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.1/lib/rack/server.rb#L239). Rack then tries to load the  app through the `config.ru`, which in turn loads your `app.rb`. The first thing in `app.rb` is `require 'sinatra'`.

Rubygems replaces the original `require` method with its own. When you call `require` it [tries to load the file normally using the existing load path and the original `require` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_374/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb#L36). If the gem hasn’t been loaded this will raise a LoadError, which [Rubygems catches](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_374/lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb#L57) before loading the gem.

With the `$DEBUG` flag set, Ruby will produce a message when an exception is raised even though it is rescued and dealt with, and this is what you’re seeing.

To avoid this simply omit the `-d` flag to your call to `rackup` (perhaps enabling warnings with `-w` would give you a sufficiently verbose output without swamping you in too much detail).

If the server isn’t starting then it will be a different issue rather than not finding Sinatra. If that is the case you’ll need to check the rest of the output for clues.

(Note that I originally thought something else was happening, and that’s what my questions int he comments were about.)

Comment: No it does not output anything. The caret just stucked there when I do `rackup config.ru` or `rackup -w config.ru`

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely issue of load path. Anyway try to setup required ruby and gems via [RVM](https://rvm.io/) and Bundler. It makes sure that Ruby interpreter and load paths are consistent.